# User to kernel transition and XMM register state

Tags: kernel, cpu-registers, windows-kernel, sse

I am using [AES-NI](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-intel-aes-ni-and-intel-secure-key-instructions#intel-aes-ni) in a kernel code. The AES new instructions use XMM registers and I want to be sure that the transition from user to kernel mode and the transition back to user mode will preserve the state of the XMM registers.

The [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545910(v=vs.85).aspx) reads:

> In 64-bit versions of Windows, the operating system preserves the SSE registers across thread (and process) switches. The result is that 64-bit driver code can safely use floating-point operations at any IRQL.

Does it confirm that I don't have to save the registers state when my kernel code is called?

Answer (score 1):

It says it preserves SSE registers, but not AVX.

Just below the link says

> To use the AVX registers in kernel mode, drivers (x86 and x64) must explicitly save and restore the AVX registers.

So it is only safe to rely on registers being automatically preserved if you use AES intrinsics that use `__m128i`, but not `__m256i` and `__m512i`.